# How long is a package in NuGet available?

Tags: nuget

We use various packages of NuGet in our company for productive applications. But we do not know how long a particular version of a package is available.

We do not want to include the packages in the source control system.

To be precise. If our source code is older than 10 years, is then a package in a particular version still available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NuGet.org you can [delist a NuGet package but not permanently delete it](https://docs.nuget.org/create/deleting-packages). Delisting removes it from the search results but it is still available for NuGet package restore.

That being said the NuGet team can permanently delete NuGet packages in exceptional circumstances. This has happened at least once, as far as I am aware, when [Oracle asked the NuGet team to remove some NuGet packages](http://blog.nuget.org/20151007/Package-Content-and-Removals.html) that were using their software or could be mistaken as being supported by Oracle.

So in practice the NuGet packages will be available as long as NuGet.org is still around. However it is hard to predict what will be happening in 10 years time.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. We consider to backup the important packages and use a own nuget feed as described her: http://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

Answer (score 0):

No one knows exactly how long a package is available.  When a new version comes out, sometimes the old version is still available and sometimes it's not.  AFAIK, they don't have a release schedule, so no one is ever sure when a new version is available until very close to the release date.

Comment: We not interested in future packages. We need to know how long a legacy package version is available.

Comment: Like I said, you never know.  Sometimes support is cut off right away, sometimes it's not.  You haven't even mentioned which packages you're using.  There is no 100% firm, infallible answer to your question.